# VS2010 Winforms DataGridView in Tabpage Loses Container Coordinates

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, containers, tabpage

The form is a complex construction with label and text controls at the top, a tab control at the bottom, and data grid views in some of the tab pages.  I had just resized the fonts in most of the controls on the form from '8' (8.25) to '10' (9.75).  Having saved it, when I reopen it numerous controls in the tab pages have either disappeared entirely or are improperly dimensioned, usually scrunched up in the upper left hand corner.  Among the malformed controls are data grid views, multi-line text boxes, labels, and buttons.  If I reposition and resize the forms, they are 'saved', but not to the dimensions I specify.  Generally when this happens I find the entire form is beyond recovery.

Why does it happen, and what should I do to keep it from happening again?

Update:

I have another form with a similar arrangement: text boxes at the top for the 'main record', a tab collection at the bottom, and custom user controls embedded in two of the pages.  Changing the font style on the tab control properties corrupted many of the controls in the subordinate pages.  This was particularly true of the two custom user controls, both of which contain DataGridViews.  However, some tab pages have nothing more than a multi-line text box, and these were also corrupted.  I suspect that the controls that were corrupted were anchored on all four sides, certain text and label controls only anchored top-left weren't affected.

I locked the controls before applying the font style, locking does not change the outcome.

Comment: I think this kind of question should be described with some snapshot. The form has `AutoScaleMode=AutoScaleMode.Font` by default. That will make the form look the same but with different scale when the font changes. Have you inadvertently changed `AutoScaleMode` to another value?

Comment: I just enrolled.  I tried posting pictures but it won't let me.Autoscale is run time.  The issue is at design time. I open the form, move and resize the grid control to the position that I want, save it, and when I reopen the form for editing it isn't where I left it.  In many cases it is 'off the screen', or at least outside of the visible range of the container.

Comment: One of the tab pages in this form has a user control of it's own.  Thus I have a hierarchy of [userControl contains [tabControl contains [TabPage contains [userControl]]]].  I created a new project in the solution, pasted the two user controls into the project, added appropriate references and made other fixes to get a clean compile, then started methodically eliminating what might be causing problems.  When I deleted the subordinate user control out of the tab page, other changes started to 'stick'.

Comment: Your problem is not the only case. I've encountered the same with a professional UI lib that is `DotNetBar`. So it's not too surprising for someone encountering such a problem with his own custom control. I don't have any idea because I've never encountered such a case with my own custom control (but as I said I've encountered the such with DotNetBar). You may want to try `Locking` your controls at design time by navigating to `Format -> Lock Controls` or right-clicking on your form and select `Lock Controls`. That may fix it but I think it's not simple to know what causes the problem.

Comment: Having determined in a test situation that having one user control embedded within a tab page which was in turn embedded in an 'outer' user control messed up the positioning in other divider tabs, I removed the 'inner' user control, whereupon I was able to fix all the other controls that had been sent to La La land.  I compiled and ran the project - everything was fine.  Having taken the precaution of backing everything up, I opened the project and added the 'inner' user control where it had been.  When I saved the project and reopened it, the other controls were shifted.

Comment: @KingKing - I tried locking the controls before applying the style change, it didn't help.